# How to set environment variables so they point to system python?

Tags: python, linux, debian

On my Debian machine I have some python versions installed. I want set environment variables so they point preinstalled python.

On my Debian machine I have few python versions installed, some applications were using some pythons from opt directory, I want to set environment variables to point to system preinstalled python. The problem is that preinstalled python looks different because binary file is in `/usr/bin/python` and libs are in `/usr/lib/python`? How is preinstalled python configured?

Usually people just download python3 which is one folder in opt, there is lib and bin folder and all you have to do is set PYTHONHOME as folder and PYTHONPATH to lib right?

Comment: What about not using environment variables. It is an old principle of Debian: programs should run also without any special environment set. Just make sure that other python interpreters are not in PATH. -- Note with virtual environment it is usually done in that way: outside venv: default python, venv will set environmant for the custom interpreters.

Comment: Then python will scream “import error: No module named site”

Comment: Debian should have provided such module. As root, could you run `python3 -m site --user-site` (and without the `3`)? If not, you broke Debian system: never overwrite system files. Else, check your env. you may get some extra variable or alias, which set wrongly python. `which python` could help (add also  `3`)

Comment: You were right! I have removed environment variables Python home and pythondir and it started working! Thank you.